# Add a /64 range of IP addresses

Tags: networking, server, 18.04, dhcp, ipv6

I have a VPS that the provider allocated me a /64 block of IPv6 addresses, I'm trying to give each domain I'm hosting in it a unique IPv6 address.

I'm using the configuration options in `/etc/network/interfaces` as follows:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 1.2.3.4
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 1.2.3.1

iface eth0 inet6 static
        address 2001:19f0:1:2:3:4:5:6
        netmask 64
```

I'm assuming the `netmask 64` directive in `eth0 inet6` block makes the server listen to any connections in `2001:19f0:1:2/64` range?

When I ping (`ping6`) IP addresses such as `2001:19f0:1:2:3:4:5:aa`, I get host unreachable error.

I would prefer not to hardcode individual IPv6 addresses. Is there any way to make the server listen to all IP addresses in this /64 block?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/q/209203/126632

Comment: Is there a firewall somewhere in there?

Comment: @MichaelHampton - Thanks, I tried the answer in the question before. It looks like the `route add` calls are not persistent after a reboot, and only works on the loopback interface. I could not ping IP addresses from outside. Thank you.

Comment: If you put it in `/etc/network/interfaces` as a `post-up` then it will persist.

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen - There is one, but ICMP traffic is allowed to pass through.

Comment: Use `nmcli` to persist changes!

Comment: https://serverfault.com/q/590038/214507 may be relevant too.